# PYTHON RECURSION Behavior when adding Elements and Counting Elements in a List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I studied Python Recursion Recently. There are few things that i am finding difficult to understand.

looks like Counting and Adding Elements of a list Through Recursion in python is almost done in a similar way. Can someone Please explain me why the calls are acting differently just by adding '1' and 'num[0]' for the below return calls:
 `return "*1*"+sum(num[1:])` and `return "*num[0]*"+sum(num[1:])`

Code for Counting Numbers in a list:

```
def count(num):
    if len(num) == 0:
        return 0
    return 1+count(num[1:])

print(count([1,2,3,4,5,6,11]))
```

Output: 7

Code for Adding Elements in a List:

```
def sum(num):
    if len(num) == 0:
        return 0
    return num[0]+sum(num[1:])

print(sum([1,2,3,4,5,6,11]))
```

Output: 32

Can someone please explain the return statement and in both of above recursion programs.

Any information that makes sense to me will be of a great help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the first case, you’re adding `1+1+1+…+1`, with a `1` for each member of the list. In the same case, you’re adding `a+b+c+…+z`, the actual members of the list.

Comment: This isn't causing you any problems in the code you've shown, but just be aware that it's probably not a good idea to write your own function named `sum` since that's the name of a builtin function. If other code called `sum` expecting the builtin but got your function instead, it might not work right, leading to obscure bugs. Using a distinct name would make that less likely to happen.

Comment: @Blckknght: That's right, should definitely avoid using builtin function as my own functions going forward. thanks a lot for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let’s write this with a loop, which is more pythonic and also probably easier for a novice to understand:

```
def count(nums):
    res = 0
    for num in nums:
        res = 1 + res
    return res

def sum(nums):
    res = 0
    for num in nums:
        res = num + res
    return res
```

The same one-word difference in the `+` operation. But now, hopefully you can understand why it’s different. The first one starts with 0, and adds 1 to that, once per element. The second one starts with 0, and adds the element to that, once per element.

---

The recursive code is doing basically the same thing, except a bit more complicated.

What it’s actually doing is pushing each element onto a stack, then starting with 0, then popping the stack until it’s empty, adding 1 or the element (respectively) for each element popped off the stack.<sup>1</sup>

But pushing a bunch of elements onto a stack and popping them off gives you the same elements, just in reverse. And adding 1 once per element, or adding up all of the elements, does the same thing counting backward as counting forward.

---

If you still don't understand, you should try stepping through the calls. Normally I'd suggest using an interactive visualizer, like [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#), but since this problem seems specifically designed to make you think functionally, let's do it that way.

Imagine that function calls in Python were just a matter of substituting in the arguments for the parameters.<sup>2</sup>

So:

```
count([1,2,3])
= 0 if len([1,2,3]) == 0 else 1 + count([2,3])
= 1 + count([2,3])
= 1 + (0 if len([2,3]) == 0 else 1 + count([3]))
= 1 + (1 + count([3]))
= 1 + (1 + (0 if len([3]) == 0 else 1 + count([])))
= 1 + (1 + (1 + count([])))
= 1 + (1 + (1 + (0 if len([]) == 0 else 1 + count([])))))
= 1 + (1 + (1 + (0)))
= 1 + (1 + (1))
= 1 + (2)
= 3

sum([5,10,1])
= 0 if len([5,10,1]) == 0 else 5 + count([10,1])
= 5 + count([10,1])
= 5 + (0 if len([10,1]) == 0 else 10 + count([1]))
= 5 + (10 + count([3]))
= 5 + (10 + (0 if len([3]) == 0 else 1 + count([])))
= 5 + (10 + (1 + count([])))
= 5 + (10 + (1 + (0 if len([]) == 0 else ??? + count([])))))
= 5 + (10 + (1 + (0)))
= 5 + (10 + (1))
= 5 + (11)
= 16
```

Also, notice that `???` above. What is `num[0]` when `num` is empty? That would raise an exception—but, because we never use that branch, it doesn't matter what it would have done.

---

<sub>1. It’s also making a whole lot of useless list copies for no reason but to let the author pretend he’s programming in Scheme rather than Python, but let’s ignore that.</sub>

<sub>2. They aren't—but as long as you aren't doing assignments or any other kind of mutation, you can't actually tell the difference. Which is why people who love pure functional languages—where you can't do assignments, etc.—love them.</sub>

Comment: Recursive is always a bit complicated. A lot of things are making sense now. Thanks again for the "Python Tutor", visualizing your Code Execution line by line is amazing and making a lot of sense to me while running a program.